# Luna latrantem canem non curat

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов, пословицы

> Луна не обращает внимания на лай собаки.
>   (Лат. *Luna latrantem canem non curat*.)

Как понимать значение этой пословицы?

Comment: Вообще-то собаки воют на луну, а не лают.

Comment: @М_Г видимо, автор латинской поговорки с вами не согласен )

Comment: Посмотрел в Нацкорпусе. К моему удивлению, есть и у нас такие авторы. "Я умел передавать лай собаки на луну... [П. А. Кропоткин. Записки революционера (1902)]

Comment: @М_Г да и, честно говоря, я сам не вижу ничего плохого в лае собак на луну...

Comment: Если серьезно, то я думаю, что собака лает, только когда рядом есть раздражитель, то есть фактически на него, а воет, когда у нее на душе плохо, то есть как бы на луну.

Comment: @М_Г вы слишком формально подходите к вопросу )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно то же, что в русском **собака лает, а караван идёт**, но в более усиленном варианте, я считаю.

**На действия и на само существование чего-то значительного и могущественного никак не может повлиять что-то мелкое, будь оно даже злобным и настырным.**

Это толкование больше подходит к варианту с караваном, который будет двигаться вперёд, даже если собаки ему досаждают. А в варианте с луной разрыв в могуществе настолько велик, что лай собак не только не может досаждать, но, вероятно, просто не будет замечен.